# I had a compilation error when i build rosjava_core source package

Tags: ros, android-core, rosjava-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a problem when i build a rosjava_core source package. The error is like this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rosjava_bootstrap:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
```

The problem come from several .java source code. Did someone know what's happen?

```
***> Building > :rosjava_bootstrap:compileJava > Resolving dependencies ':rosjava_b:rosjava_bootstrap:compileJava
/home/elisa/my_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/message/DefaultMessageFactory.java:42: type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object
    return messageProxyFactory.newMessageProxy(messageType, messageDefinition);
                                              ^
/home/elisa/my_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/message/MessageFieldType.java:56: type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object
    return messageFactory.newFromType(messageIdentifier.getType());
                                     ^
/home/elisa/my_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/message/service/ServiceRequestMessageFactory.java:43: type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object
    return messageProxyFactory.newMessageProxy(serviceType,
                                              ^
/home/elisa/my_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/message/service/ServiceResponseMessageFactory.java:43: type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object
    return messageProxyFactory.newMessageProxy(serviceType,
                                              ^
Note: /home/elisa/my_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/message/MessageImpl.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
4 errors***
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36018/i-had-a-compilation-error-when-i-build-rosjava_core-source-package/) by [loulou0219](https://answers.ros.org/users/2562/loulou0219/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you're using the latest JDK (both Sun and OpenJDK should work). I am not able to reproduce this issue.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0